# JTree File model doesn't work after export to jar file

Tags: file, jar, jtree

I had a jTree file model root set to "file/" all works fine, when the application export to jar file, it can't works. Any idea why does it happen?

Comment: It does not work = ? Please post any specific behaviours, exception logs...

Comment: I run it using eclipse is work fine. When i run using jar file the jTree doesn't show out the file

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the file to your classpatch or bundle it in your exported jar?

Comment: how to add the file to classpath i got bundle it in my jar file.